# Properly position two DIVs - One as a fixed sidebar, and other as expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code to create a simple website with two sections; a sidebar and the main content:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #FFF5BA;
  width: 200px;
}

.main {
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 1);
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The HTML is as goes:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="main">
</div>
```

The problem I have happens when you dynamically add more content to the main section with JavaScript. If you add enough to require scrolling, then the sidebar will not grow as you scroll down.

Ideally I would like to leave the sidebar as fixed content that scrolls with you, but I have read that you cannot combine flexbox with position: fixed.

If you need to see the complete here it is:
https://codepen.io/wulfenn/pen/LYNRNEv (apologies in advance if the code is sloppy; I am still learning)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated `html` code by moving modal code outside of `container` class.


I have used `position:sticky` on `sidebar` class and assign `height:100vh`. so that it would not scroll if  main content height is bigger than `100vh`.


I have also added  dummy `book-add` div to create more height of main content.

> View results in full screen and only first add button will work.

```js
// Declare the Object constructor.
function Book(title, author, pages, isbn, read, bookURL) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.read = read;
  this.bookURL = bookURL;
}

Book.prototype.toggleStatus = function () {
  if (this.read == 'Read') {
    this.read = 'Not Read';
    return 1;
  } else if (this.read == 'Not Read') {
    this.read = 'Reading';
    return 2;
  } else if (this.read == 'Reading') {
    this.read = 'Read';
    return 3;
  }
}

// Initalize library variables.
let myLibrary = [];
const container = document.querySelector('.books-container');


// Display and Hide the "Add a Book" form.
const popup = document.querySelector('.form-popup');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancel-btn');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  popup.style.display = 'block'; // Show
})

cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  popup.style.display = 'none'; // Hide
})

// #### Book Form Start 
// ##

// Get the form values
const form = document.getElementById('form1');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  const title = document.forms[0].elements[1].value;
  const author = document.forms[0].elements[2].value;
  const pages = document.forms[0].elements[3].value;
  const isbn = document.forms[0].elements[4].value;
  const bookURL = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
  // Check which radio button has been selected.
  let read = '';
  if (document.getElementById('read').checked) {
    read = 'Read';
  } else if (document.getElementById('unread').checked) {
    read = 'Not Read';
  } else {
    read = 'Reading';
  }

  // Prevent page from refreshing and closing the form popup.
  event.preventDefault();
  popup.style.display = 'none';

  // Add our book.
  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, isbn, read, bookURL);

  // Display the books and reset the form.
  render();
  form.reset();

})

// Display our cover preview. 
const cover = document.querySelector('.cover-preview');
const isbnField = document.getElementById('isbn'); // In case ISBN has been typed
const coverURL = document.getElementById('url'); // In case URL has been used.

coverURL.addEventListener('change', function () {
  cover.style.background = `url(${document.forms[0].elements[0].value})`;
  cover.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
})

isbnField.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (document.forms[0].elements[0].value == '') { // URL takes preference as it's chosen by user.
    cover.style.background = `url(http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/${document.forms[0].elements[4].value}-M.jpg)`;
    cover.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
  }
})


// Add a given book to myLibrary array
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, isbn, read, bookURL) {
  let book = new Book(title, author, pages, isbn, read, bookURL);
  myLibrary.push(book);
}

// ##
// #### Book Form End


// Display the books in our HTML

function render() {

  // Clear our space first.
  const existingDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-book]');
  existingDivs.forEach((div) => {
    div.remove();
  });


  for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('book');
    // Determine our cover. URL overrides ISBN.
    if (myLibrary[i]['bookURL']) {
      element.style.background = `url(${myLibrary[i]['bookURL']})`;
    } else {
      element.style.background = `url(http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/${myLibrary[i]['isbn']}-M.jpg)`;
    }
    element.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    element.setAttribute("data-book", i);

    // Create our mouse enter divs to display book information.
    let infoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    infoDiv.classList.add('book-info');
    infoDiv.style.display = 'none'; // Set to not display by deafult until mouse enter.
    let titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
    titleDiv.classList.add('info-title');
    titleDiv.textContent = myLibrary[i]['title'];
    let authorDiv = document.createElement('div');
    authorDiv.classList.add('info-author');
    authorDiv.textContent = `by ${myLibrary[i]['author']}`;
    let pagesDiv = document.createElement('div');
    pagesDiv.classList.add('info-pages');
    pagesDiv.textContent = `Pages: ${myLibrary[i]['pages']}`;

    // Create our status buttons and our delete button.
    let buttonsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    buttonsDiv.classList.add('info-buttons');
    let readTag = document.createElement('button');
    readTag.classList.add('button-status');
    readTag.setAttribute('data-bookstatus', i);

    if (myLibrary[i]['read'] == 'Read') {
      readTag.style.background = '#EBFFE5';
      readTag.textContent = '✔';
    } else if (myLibrary[i]['read'] == 'Not Read') {
      readTag.style.background = '#FFC1B1';
      readTag.textContent = '❌';
    } else {
      readTag.style.background = '#FFFFEA';
      readTag.textContent = '';
    }

    let removeTag = document.createElement('button');
    removeTag.classList.add('button-status');
    removeTag.textContent = '';
    removeTag.setAttribute("data-bookremove", i);



    // Add everything together
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(readTag);
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(removeTag);
    infoDiv.appendChild(titleDiv);
    infoDiv.appendChild(authorDiv);
    infoDiv.appendChild(pagesDiv);
    infoDiv.appendChild(buttonsDiv);
    element.appendChild(infoDiv);


    // Insert the finished product
    container.insertBefore(element, container.firstChild);
  }

  // Display book information on mouseover
  const bookFrames = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.book'));

  bookFrames.forEach((bookFrame) => {
    bookFrame.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
      bookFrame.firstChild.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  bookFrames.forEach((bookFrame) => {
    bookFrame.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
      bookFrame.firstChild.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });

  // Add functionality to our status and delete buttons

  const statusButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bookstatus'));
  statusButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      let index = button.getAttribute('data-bookstatus');
      let x = myLibrary[index].toggleStatus();

      switch (x) {
        case 1:
          button.style.background = '#FFC1B1';
          button.textContent = '❌';
          break;
        case 2:
          button.style.background = '#FFFFEA';
          button.textContent = '';
          break;
        case 3:
          button.style.background = '#EBFFE5';
          button.textContent = '✔';
          break;

      }
    });
  });



  //Remove button
  const removeButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bookremove]'));
  removeButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      let index = button.getAttribute('data-bookremove');
      const bookToRemove = document.querySelector(`div[data-book='${index}']`);
      bookToRemove.remove();  // Remove it from the DOM.
      myLibrary.splice(index, 1); //  Remove it from our array so it does not render again.
    });
  });


}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special Elite&display=swap");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Special Elite";
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #fff5ba;
  width: 200px;
  height:100vh;
}

.main {
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 1);
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.books-container {
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px black;
}

.book-info {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.info-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px black;
}

.info-author {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.info-pages {
  position: relative;
  top: 23%;
  color: #fff5ba;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.info-buttons {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
}

.button-status {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 25px;
}

.button-status:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.book-add {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px black;
}

.add-btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: inherit;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.add-btn:hover {
  background-color: #fff5ba;
}

.cover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.cover-preview-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover-preview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.book-form-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #836953;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.form-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: url(assets/books.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px black;
}

.form-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: url(assets/wood.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px black;
}

.book-form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff5ba;
}

.entry-box {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-btn {
  margin: 40px 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: inherit;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px 1px black;
  outline: none;
}

.form-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="my-library">My Library</div>
    <div class="menu">Home</div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="books-container">
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
      <div class="book-add">
        <button class="add-btn">+</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-popup">
  <div class="book-form-container">

    <div class="form-header"><br />Add a Book</div>
    <div class="book-form">
      <form id="form1">
        <div class="cover-preview-container">Cover
          <div class="cover-preview"></div>
          <div><span style="font-size: small">Or enter the link to the cover image:</span> <br /><input class="entry-box" id="url" type="url" placeholder="https://"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="title"> Title </label><br />
          <input class="entry-box" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter the book title." required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="author"> Author</label><br />
          <input class="entry-box" type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Enter the Author." required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="pages"> Pages</label><br />
          <input class="entry-box" type="number" id="pages" name="pages" min="1" placeholder="0" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="isbn"> ISBN <span style="font-size: small"><i><sup>what is this?</sup></i></span></label><br />
          <input class="entry-box" type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn" placeholder="(optional)">
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
          <label for="read">Read</label>
          <input id="read" type="radio" name="status" value="read" required>
          <label for="unread">Not Read</label>
          <input id="unread" type="radio" name="status" value="unread" required>
          <label for="reading">Reading</label>
          <input id="reading" type="radio" name="status" value="reading" required>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="form-footer">
      <button id="form-add-btn" type="submit" class="form-btn" form="form1">Add</button>
      <button id="cancel-btn" class="form-btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Works wonderful too and gives me more code to study! So position: sticky does not remove the element out of the flow and can still be used with flexbox?

Comment: yes ```position:sticky``` can be used with ```flexbox```.

Comment: Why are you provoking the author to vote for your answer, meanwhile, when the author has already chosen my answer, it is not correct. Moreover, if you size your answer to the full screen, then below the `books-container` class I saw a gap (https://ibb.co/fDG92jW), which is no longer the norm.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov the gap is because there is not height specify to main content and it can be solved easily and btw that was not the main issue of the problem. Correct answer and answers with more generic methods should be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: The author himself has the right to choose the answer that he likes best. And the author chose my answer, but after that you ask the author to choose your answer as correct - I repeat again, this is incorrect.